# SQL: How to show event beneath all regions depending on flag (in absence of many-to-many join)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm displaying a page listing events across different cities:

> **Los Angeles** 
> Soap Festival 13 Feb
>  Cookie Contest 8 May
>
> **New York**
>   Star Trek Convention 5 May
>
> **Miami**
>   Swimsuit Contest

Events can only be linked to a single city (region_id is on the event table) or flagged as being in 'all cities' ('show_in_all_cities' flag). In the absence of a many-to-many joining table i.e. event_city, is there a way I could get an event that's flagged with 'show_in_all_cities' to appear beneath each of the cities?

My current query below (not taking into account the 'all cities' flag):

```
SELECT
  event.*,
  region.name
FROM event
  INNER JOIN region
    ON region.region_id = event.region_id
WHERE event.`date` >= CURDATE()
ORDER BY region.sort_order, event.date ASC
```

I'm then looping through with PHP to output and display the city headings.

Comment: While this could be done in SQL, I would recommend doing it application logic. That way you will have simpler queries, and the "all cities" events won't be loaded from the database each and every time.

Comment: what's the `region_id` for an event with `show_in_all_cities` flag set?

Comment: It will be set to a valid region id, meaning 'primary region'. Essentially it's held in this region but should be visible in others too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the flag to the order by clause:

```
SELECT event.*, region.name
FROM event       
INNER JOIN region 
ON region.region_id = event.region_id 
WHERE event.`date` >= CURDATE()         
ORDER BY event.show_in_all_cities, region.sort_order, event.date ASC
```

(assuming that the flag is set to a higher value for the all-cities events, otherwise:

```
ORDER BY event.show_in_all_cities DESC, region.sort_order, event.date ASC
```

)

Answer (score 0):

Just add `or (event.SHOW_IN_ALL_CITIES=1 )` (if it is 0/1 int flag for instance) to your JOIN condition. In this case for each event with this flag ALL regions are added to the output set.

```
SELECT
  event.*,
  region.name
FROM event
  INNER JOIN region
    ON (region.region_id = event.region_id) or (event.SHOW_IN_ALL_CITIES=1 )
WHERE event.`date` >= CURDATE()
ORDER BY region.sort_order, event.date ASC
```